# SQL Access - Using Top Command Some Data Missing

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have used the Top Command to order and take the top 7 evaluation changes, the results are correct and the right records are displayed however the evaluation changes themselves are not actually displayed.

```
SELECT [Employee].EmployeeID, [Employee].Name, 
(SELECT [Evaluation History].[Evaluation Change (2015-2017)] FROM [Evaluation History] WHERE [Evaluation History].EmployeeID=Employee.EmployeeID) AS [2015-2017 Evaluation Growth]
FROM Employee;
```

[First Query Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9CMa.png)

I then used the following code to order them by the growth and then pick the top 7 which works.

```
SELECT TOP 7 *
FROM qryEmployeeEvaluationChanges
ORDER BY [2015-2017 Evaluation Growth] DESC;
```

However in the results the Evaluation Growth column shows empty despite the ordering being correct. 
[Second Query Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1bM2.png)

(APOLOGIES, Total Novice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a join instead of a subselect

```
  SELECT TOP 7 [Employee].EmployeeID, [Employee].Name
    , [Evaluation History].[Evaluation Change (2015-2017)] AS [2015-2017 Evaluation Growth]
  FROM Employee
  INNER JOIN [Evaluation History] ON [Evaluation History].EmployeeID=Employee.EmployeeID
  ORDER BY [2015-2017 Evaluation Growth] DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is the same results, correct ordering but no growth data?

Comment: Thanks again however unfortunately it still does not work, i get an Enter Parameter Value for [2015-2017 Evaluation Growth].

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but I solved it with this

```
   SELECT TOP 7 [Employee].EmployeeID, [Employee].Name
    , [Evaluation History].[Evaluation Change (2015-2017)]
  FROM Employee
  INNER JOIN [Evaluation History] ON [Evaluation History].EmployeeID=Employee.EmployeeID
  ORDER BY [Evaluation Change (2015-2017)] DESC
```

Comment: Getting rid of the AS